# Code for multiplying list elements list[i] and list[j] only if i<j

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

For example, if `a=[1,2,3,4,5]`, I want 1 multiplied with all the other elements, 2 multiplied with 3,4,5 and so on. I want the multiplication products appended to a list for the final output.

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work (gives only an empty list as output):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = []

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if i<j:
            b[i]=a[i]*a[j]
print(b)
```

Comment: Hold on you *assign to `b[i]` but that does not exists?

Answer (score 3):

If I run this in [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), I get an:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

That is because `b` is an empty list so `b[0]` (or any other `b[i]`) is out of range.

What you however aim to do is probably:

```
b = [a[i]*a[j] for i in range(len(a))
               for j in range(i+1,len(a))]
```

which generates:

```
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20]
```

(which is `[1*2, 1*3, 1*4, 1*5, 2*3, 2*4, 2*5, 3*4, 3*5, 4*5]`)

Here the bounds are *not* checked explicitly, we simply set the `range(..)` of `j` to begin at `i+1` (so we simply know that every `j` will be greater than `i`).

An alternative - that is probably more elegant - could be to use `itertools.combinations` module:

```
from itertools import combinations

b = [x*y for x,y in combinations(a,2)]
```

Comment: @NoahCristino: but this is simply a nested for loop **in list comprehension**.

Comment: You changed it. Looks better now

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using itertools:

```
import itertools as it

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [el_i * el_j for (i, el_i), (j, el_j) in it.product(enumerate(a), repeat = 2) if i<j]
```

Also, as others pointed out, you probably want to do this in your example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = []

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if i<j:
            # Use append here as b is initialised as empty list
            b.append(a[i]*a[j])   
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do all the multiplications you want. You'll notice I print the results rather than assign them, since your attempt would repeatedly assign to the same value. When you figure out what you really want, you can fix it.

```
for j in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(j):
        print a[i]*a[j] ,
    print
```

Comment: Here `j` will be less than `i`. Although since multiplication is commutative, it will not matter here, in general this program does not hold.

Comment: Read more carefully.

Comment: you swapped the ranges. But this can alter the order of the elements.

Comment: No i didn't. The top loop was always `j`.

Comment: I mean compared with the original question. What I mean is that for a generic operator (not `*` per se), this can result in a list where the same elements occur, but in a different order.

Comment: actually even for multiplication this holds. The order should be `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]` and your program outputs `[2, 3, 6, ...]`...

Comment: Who knows what the order "should be"? The OP's code expects `b` to end up with the same legth as `a`. It would assign several results to each index of `b`, with each overwriting the last. This is clearly nonsense, so who knows what it should have been? My guess is it's missing a sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an index that does not exist. Therefore, you should use the `list.append` method instead.